# C# 3.5 refactor method using generic method

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

Wondering if there is a good way to re-factor this working code 'switch' statement using generic method to make it more elegant and eliminate switch on type names:

```
        private void CreateFragDetailsHistoryLogEntry(string field, FRAGMENT_ANALYSIS fragment, ModifiedMemberInfo info, RegistriesLinqDataContext context, string analyteName)
        {
               LABRESULT_CHANGE_TRACKING tracking = new LABRESULT_CHANGE_TRACKING();

               string originalValue = null, newValue = null;

               var typeName = info.OriginalValue == null ? info.CurrentValue.GetType().Name : info.OriginalValue.GetType().Name;

                switch (typeName)
                {
                    case "DateTime":

                        originalValue = (info.OriginalValue as DateTime?).HasValue ? String.Empty : (info.OriginalValue as DateTime?).Value.ToShortDateString());
                        newValue = (info.CurrentValue as DateTime?).HasValue ? String.Empty : (info.CurrentValue as DateTime?).Value.ToShortDateString());
                        break;

                    case "String":

                        originalValue = info.OriginalValue.ToString();
                        newValue = info.CurrentValue.ToString();
                        break;

                    case "Boolean":

                        originalValue = (bool)info.OriginalValue ? "True" : "False";
                        newValue = (bool)info.CurrentValue ? "True" : "False";
                        break;

                    case "Char":
                        originalValue = ((char?)info.OriginalValue).HasValue ? (char?)info.OriginalValue == 'Y' ? "True" : "False" : "False";
                        newValue = ((char?)info.CurrentValue).HasValue ? (char?)info.CurrentValue == 'Y' ? "True" : "False" : "False";
                        break;
                }
                tracking.CHANGE_DESCRIPTION = @"Fragment #" + fragment.FRAGMENT_ID_NUMBER  + @" field """ + field +  @""" changed from """ + originalValue 
                    + @""" to """ + newValue + @""".";
                tracking.CHANGE_FIELD = "Fragment Details";
                break;               

        tracking.SetAsInsertOnSubmit();

        LabResultsTrackingManager manager = new LabResultsTrackingManager();

        manager.Update(tracking);

    }
```

This method creates and writes to a database changes to existing LINQ entities.

Comment: This is a question for codereview.stackexchange.com, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @Judah wtf is codereview? why cant we discuss code patterns and code style on SO? this is getting ridiculous :o)

Comment: @stefan StackOverflow is for questions that can have definitive answers. The question -- "how can I refactor my crappy code" -- is subjective. It's a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @judah - this is not "crappy" but perfectly working code and I was wondering if it could be re-written in more elegant way.

Comment: No offense meant; the "refactor my [problematic/could-be-improved] code" is what I was trying to convey. In any case, subjective questions about how to best refactor code is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com FWIW, I found this question via moderation, where someone flagged this question as not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Judah No offense taken. Oddly enough I was checking answers from time to time and didn't see it flagged as anything.

Comment: Yeah. Frankly, I don't mind if this sort of thing goes on StackOverflow. CodeReview is a better place for stuff like this, but barring any "move this post to CodeReview" moderator tool, I'd just as soon leave it as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three potential solutions.

1. Use an `if/else` chain:

   ```
   var type = info.OriginalValue == null ? info.CurrentValue.GetType() : info.OriginalValue.GetType();

   if (type == typeof(DateTime)) 
   { 
       ...
   }
   else if (type == typeof(string)) 
   {
       ...
   }
   ...
   ```
2. Use dynamic dispatch

   ```
   dynamic dynamicThis = this;
   var result = dyanmicThis.ConvertValues(info.OriginalValue, info.CurrentValue);
   originalValue = result.Item1;
   newValue = result.Item2;

   ...

   Tuple<object, object> ConvertValues(DateTime? originalValue, DateTime? currentValue) 
   {
       return Tuple.Create(originalValue != null ? originalValue.Value.ToShortDateString() : "", currentValue != null ? currentValue);
   }

   Tuple<object, object> ConvertValues(string originalValue, string currentValue) 
   {
       return Tuple.Create(originalValue, currentValue);
   }
   ```

   This solution uses the dynamic language runtime to pick the correct method overload at runtime, so it is not without performance cost.  Though unless it's called a *lot* it is probably inconsequential.
3. Finally, you could also have a dictionary of `Dictionary<Type, Action>` and populate that with a bunch of lambdas that implement each choice in your logic chain:

   ```
   var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Action>();
   dictionary[typeof(DateTime?)] = () => {
       originalValue = (info.OriginalValue as DateTime?).HasValue ? String.Empty : (info.OriginalValue as DateTime?).Value.ToShortDateString());
       newValue = (info.CurrentValue as DateTime?).HasValue ? String.Empty : (info.CurrentValue as DateTime?).Value.ToShortDateString());
   };
   dictionary[typeof(string)] = () => {
       originalValue = info.OriginalValue.ToString();
       newValue = info.CurrentValue.ToString();        
   };
   var type = info.OriginalValue == null ? info.CurrentValue.GetType() : info.OriginalValue.GetType();
   dictionary[type]();  // Invoke the appropriate lambda
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I like 2nd solution but can't use it unfortunately since I am in 3.5. Will probably end up using 3rd method